# Onclick is only triggered once after assigning functions through for loop

Tags: javascript

In those for loop, I am assigning a function to a close button that will essentially remove a mark tag from some text.

```
    for (q = 0; q < json_response.trainer.annotation.length; q++) {
        let close_ = document.getElementById(`cl_${x3}_${q}`);
        console.log(close_)
        close_.onclick = function () {
            delete_ent(this);
        };
    };


function delete_ent($this) {
    let all_text = $this.parentNode.parentNode.innerHTML;
    console.log($this, $this.parentNode);
    let test1 = $this.parentNode.innerHTML;
    let replace_text = test1.split("<span>");
    // console.log(replace_text[0]);
    let updated_text = all_text.replace(`${$this.parentNode.outerHTML}`, `${replace_text[0]}`);
    $this.parentNode.parentNode.innerHTML = updated_text;
}
```

It works exactly as intended for the first mark tag removed, but then after it's updated the text, the other close buttons stop working.

This is for a chrome extension

Comment: You are setting the `innerHTML` of the parent node, and by doing so, replacing everything that was first part of that parent node, including all the events you attached to any of the child elements.

Comment: could you not just use `removeChild` instead of changing the `innerHtml`?  If not you would need to use a delegated click event on the parent (if you go this route, it would probably be easier to give your buttons a class rather than targeting ids separately)

Comment: (Offtopic PS:) 1. use `for (let q = 0` inside the for loop — otherwise you're bloating the window scope by using `for (q =` ... `console.log(window.q); // N`. 2. the `;` after the for body is unnecessary.

Comment: `let replace_text = test1.split("<span>");` is the worst possible thing you could do, since that splitted `<span>` will be removed from the resulting array.

Comment: **Never** use `onclick` handlers on already existing elements in the DOM. Always use `.addEventListener()`, unless you're creating brand new Elements from in-memory, then `on*` handlers *can* be used with special caution not to override already attached handlers.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I was trying to disgard the span because I wanted to replace that mark tag's html with just raw text in a paragraph